# I am getting an error when running pytest but the code is working when I use flask. The error in pytest is caused by ckeditor. Any idea how to fix it?

Tags: python, flask, pytest, ckeditor

The code was working before I added `ckeditor` but when I run `pytest -q --capture=no` I get an error.

Here is the documentation for `ckeditor` https://flask-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic.html#initialization

I tried changing `ckeditor` to a different name to

`sckeditor = CKEditor()` but it makes no difference. I thought that might be causing the error.

wsgi.py

```
from flask_migrate import Migrate
   
from app import create_app, db

from app.config import Config

app = create_app(Config)

 
# This is used in flask-migrate to downgrade
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

app.config.from_object(Config)



from flask_migrate import Migrate
   
from app import create_app, db

from app.config import Config

app = create_app(Config)

 
# This is used in flask-migrate to downgrade
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

app.config.from_object(Config)
```

**init**.py

```
from flask_ckeditor import CKEditor
editor = CKEditor()


def create_app():
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    db.init_app(app)    
    editor.init_app(app)
    ...
    return app
```

config.py

```
class Config(object): 
    ...
   CKEDITOR_PKG_TYPE = 'standard'
    ...

class PytestConfig(Config): 
     ...
```

forms.py

```
class Postform(FlaskForm):
    '''   
    This is in "/post/new" and  "/post/edit/<int:post_id>" and "/post/delete/<int:post_id>" routes.
    The forms are title and content
    '''
    title = StringField('title', validators=[DataRequired('title is required')],)  
    content = CKEditorField('content', validators=[DataRequired('content is required')]) # need better phrasing then 'content is required'
```

new_post.html

```
        {{ sckeditor.load() }}
        {{ sckeditor.config(name='content') }}
        {{ sckeditor.load(custom_url=url_for('static', filename='ckeditor/ckeditor.js')) }}
```

edit_post.html

```
<body>
        {{ ckeditor.load() }}
        {{ ckeditor.config(name='content') }}
        {{ ckeditor.load(custom_url=url_for('static', filename='ckeditor/ckeditor.js')) }}
</body>
```

Here is the error. Notice how in test_routes.py I am getting the error from

test_routes.py

```
from app import create_app 
from app.config import PytestConfig
 


app = create_app(PytestConfig)
app.app_context().push()
```

```
_______________________________________________ ERROR collecting app/tests/test_routes.py ________________________________________________ 
app\tests\test_routes.py:14: in <module>
    app = create_app(PytestConfig)
app\__init__.py:74: in create_app
    ckeditor.init_app(app)
..\..\..\..\Anaconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\flask_ckeditor\__init__.py:174: in init_app
    app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
..\..\..\..\Anaconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\flask\scaffold.py:57: in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
..\..\..\..\Anaconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py:1028: in register_blueprint
    blueprint.register(self, options)
..\..\..\..\Anaconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\flask\blueprints.py:305: in register
    raise ValueError(
E   ValueError: The name 'ckeditor' is already registered for a different blueprint. Use 'name=' to provide a unique name.
======================================================== short test summary info ========================================================= 
ERROR app/tests/test_routes.py - ValueError: The name 'ckeditor' is already registered for a different blueprint. Use 'name=' to provide...
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

The code runs in the flask app when I type flask run.

But if I change **init**.py to

`app = Flask(__name__) ckeditor = CKEditor(app)` 
I get the same error when I type flask run.

Here is the error

```
flask run
 * Serving Flask app 'wsgi' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 351, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 407, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 260, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\flaskcodeusethis\flaskblog2\wsgi.py", line 7, in <module>
    app = create_app(Config)
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\flaskcodeusethis\flaskblog2\app\__init__.py", line 78, in create_app
    sckeditor.init_app(app)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\flask_ckeditor\__init__.py", line 174, in init_app
    app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\flask\scaffold.py", line 57, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1028, in register_blueprint
    blueprint.register(self, options)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\flask\blueprints.py", line 305, in register
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The name 'ckeditor' is already registered for a different blueprint. Use 'name=' to provide a unique name.
```

Thanks for your help.